# mmap map size limit

Tags: c++, mmap, memcpy, segmentation-fault

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting segmentation fault SIGSEGV in memcpy after mmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270689/getting-segmentation-fault-sigsegv-in-memcpy-after-mmap)

I'm using mmap() in my cpp code to map a large size area (100,000,000 bytes ~ 100MB).

From man mmap I understand that I can only know whether it succeeded or not, I cannot know how much size it succeeded to map.

In my case, I could read that area iteratively with a buffer of 8192 bytes, but after I read ~24MB I get SIGSEGV - means that mmap didn't map the **entire** area successfully?

I'm reading by a memcpy function to copy from the mapped area to my buffer on the heap. (I see the same behavior also when the buffer is on the stack).

How can I know if it mapped the entire area or not? And if it mapped the entire area then why do I get the SIGSEGV after around 24MB of bytes read?

Thanks!

Comment: If it succeeded, it mapped the entire area.  99.7% of the time, the bug is in your code and not in the OS.  As for why you're getting a SIGSEGV after 24 MB, it's impossible to say without seeing your code.

Comment: You can see the code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270689/getting-segmentation-fault-sigsegv-in-memcpy-after-mmap

Comment: You have a bug in your code - it's crashing at around 0.25 of the way through your buffer because you're incrementing a pointer by a factor of 4 too much each time - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13274634/253056

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int *  addr = reinterpret_cast<int *>(mmap(NULL, length , PROT_READ, flags , fd, 0));
// ...    
int * initaddr = addr;

char buffer[jbuffer_size];

void *ret_val = buffer;
int read_length = length;

while(ret_val == buffer || read_length<jbuffer_size) {
    ret_val = memcpy(buffer, addr,jbuffer_size);
    addr+=jbuffer_size;
    read_length -= jbuffer_size;
}
```

So, your termination condition looks wrong: you *decrement* `read_length` and loop until it is *less than* `buffer_size`.

Also, you're incrementing `addr` by `buffer_size` *integers* (it is an `int*`), *not* bytes. So, you're advancing `addr` 4 times too fast.

BTW, in other code: `lseek` takes and returns an `off_t`, not a `size_t`.

---

Edit: most of these bugs are pointed out in the other question already, so I'm not sure this one adds anything.

Comment: It's not add a thing. I also commented there that this is not the main bug. The answer is now there...

Comment: Actually, the answer to that question is _also_ included in my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

If you get a segmentation violation, it's not because the `mmap` didn't succeed, it's because of something else.  You are trying to access a segment outside of any region mapped into your process' virtual memory.

Check your program's memory accesses against the set of maps your program has allocated.  Consider leveraging `pmap`, `strace` and `gdb`.